# Masking column in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, data-masking

First of all, as an admin of SQL Server, I'm trying to use standard database for masking column.

```
CREATE TABLE [Person].[MyEmailAddress]
(
    [MyBusinessEntityID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MyEmailAddressID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmailAddress] [nvarchar](50) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'email()') NULL, --<== masked
    [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyEmailAddress_BusinessEntityID_EmailAddressID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [MyBusinessEntityID] ASC,
        [MyEmailAddressID] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Then, I created a new stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Person].[Email_Address]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * from [Person].[EmailAddress]
END
GO
```

Then, I created a new login user

```
create login AdvUserTest004
with password = 'Test123'

create user User004
for login AdvUserTest004

-- add user to the database owner role
exec sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'User004'
```

Setting the user role by referring this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15) to `db_datawriter` and `db_datareader`. Without these two memberships, the tables didn't appear.

Then, I tried to login with 'AdvUserTest004' with SQL Server authentication mode. Tried to execute select statement

```
select * from [Person].[EmailAddress]
```

The output result looks good, masked.

[image: output of masked column]

But the stored procedure above didn't appear. So, by referring this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#SSMSProcedure), giving permission to execute.

[image: user permission]

Now, stored procedure appear as usual. Then, execute the stored procedure

```
exec [Person].[Email_Address]
```

The result looks like this:

[image: unmasked]

So the question is,

1. Why is the email column **unmasked** when it executes in stored procedure but it is masked in select statement?
2. How should the email column mask when it executes in stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You re making your user a `db_owner`. If you check [Chart of SQL Server Permissions](https://aka.ms/sql-permissions-poster):

[image]

you can see that members of this role can `UNMASK` any data. This can be easily check with the code below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[StackOverflow];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]
(
    [email] NVARCHAR(128) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'email()')
);

INSERT INTO [dbo].[StackOverflow] ([email])
VALUES ('text1@gmail.bg')
      ,('text2@gmail.bg')
      ,('text3@gmail.bg');

SELECT [email]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];

GO

DROP USER IF EXISTS [Daleman];

CREATE USER [Daleman] WITHOUT LOGIN;  
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[StackOverflow] TO [Daleman];  

GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'Daleman'; 

SELECT [email]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];
REVERT;

GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'Daleman';


EXECUTE AS USER = 'Daleman'; 

SELECT [email]
FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow];
REVERT;
```

where I am:

- creating a new table and query it (as I am `sys.admin` I can `unmask`)
- creating a new user with access to query the table (who cannot `unmask` and see the data masked)
- making the user `db_owner` and showing now the user can see the original data

Here is the output of the execution code:

[image]

So, I guess you are not testing correctly the case where you are seeing the data masked.

Comment: thxs for your code & explanation. Q, why do you create user without login ? I understood the rest of the code.

Comment: @Daleman for simplicity because there is no need to connect  with it :-) you can test using `EXECUTE AS` to test the code. Also, when using `EXECUTE AS`, use `REVERT` in order to ensure you are with the original security context after the test is run.

Comment: And both of you should be using ALTER ROLE rather than the deprecated sp_addrolemember.

Answer (score 0):

I just got example from this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/databases/wide-world-importers/sample-scripts/dynamic-data-masking/DemonstrateDDM.SQL)

```
-- Demonstrate Dynamic Data Masking
-- 
-- Make sure to connect using a privileged user such as the database owner or sysadmin

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = N'GreatLakesUser')
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN GreatLakesUser 
    WITH PASSWORD = N'SQLRocks!00',
         CHECK_POLICY = OFF,
         CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF,
         DEFAULT_DATABASE = WideWorldImporters;
END;
GO

USE WideWorldImporters;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'GreatLakesUser')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER GreatLakesUser FOR LOGIN GreatLakesUser;
END;
GO

ALTER ROLE [Great Lakes Sales] ADD MEMBER GreatLakesUser;
GO

-- grant SELECT rights to role principal
GRANT SELECT ON Purchasing.Suppliers TO [Great Lakes Sales];
GO

-- select with current UNMASK rights (NOTE row count and data values), assuming you are connected using a privileged user
SELECT SupplierID, SupplierName, BankAccountName, BankAccountBranch, BankAccountCode, BankAccountNumber FROM Purchasing.Suppliers;

-- impersonate the user GreatLakesUser
EXECUTE AS USER = 'GreatLakesUser';
GO

-- select with impersonated MASKED rights (NOTE row count and data values)
SELECT SupplierID, SupplierName, BankAccountName, BankAccountBranch, BankAccountCode, BankAccountNumber FROM Purchasing.Suppliers;
GO

REVERT;
GO

-- Clean-up (optional)
/*
REVOKE SELECT ON Purchasing.Suppliers TO [Great Lakes Sales];
GO
DROP USER GreatLakesUser;
GO
DROP LOGIN GreatLakesUser;
GO
*/
```